# Use scaled data on test file

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to fit a model of logistic regression on my first file(F1) of data and i want to test it
 on another file named F2(The same exersise of another year).
Code on F1:

```
   sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
   X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
   X_test =  sc.transform(X_test) 
   logistic = LogisticRegression(random_state =0,max_iter = 300 ,penalty = 'l2')
   model = logistic.fit(X,y)
   ScaledObj = X_train
```

How can i do to use the scaled data in my test file please 
I did this but i don"t knwo how to use **ScaledObj** on my test 
Code on my File Test(F2)

```
 F2 = pd.read_csv("F2.csv", sep =',')
 y_test = F2['y']
 X_test = F2.copy()
 del X_test['y']
 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
 proba= model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
 Auc_Test = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, proba)
```

Comment: Assuming you still have the fitted scaler stored in memory (you haven't exited the script or session), you use it the same way you did the first time around, with `.transform` on the new `X` data

Comment: @G.Anderson can u edit my code ? please did'nt understand

Comment: @G.Anderson got error when adding this line

Comment: You don't need anything edited, you already do the necessary in the first script, just do the same in the second `X_test =  sc.transform(X_test)`. If you're getting an error, please edit you question to add it so that we can see where the issue is

Comment: why do you have del X_test['y']?

Comment: Know it works but don't need to use ScaledObj of my train please?? @G.Anderson

Comment: @micric to have features matrix only

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. If you have the trained scaler from your training data, you should then use the same scaler to transform all future test or production data

Comment: Ah thank you its clear now

Comment: @G.Anderson have other question please. Shall i keep the scale for X_test of my F1 (Thirs line of my code)?

Comment: See my answer, hopefully that helps clear up any confusion

Answer (score 0):

For best practice in a machine learning project, the typical workflow goes like this:

1. `fit` the scaler to the training data separated from the testing data
2. `transform` the training data (you did this already with your `fit_transform` step)
3. `transform` the test data using the already-fitted scaler*. This prevents any [data leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/) between your training and testing data
4. Use the same fitted scaler* to `transform` any other validation or production data.

*-Note that the scaler only lives in memory, so if you want to use it in another script, you can use something like `pickle` or `joblib` to save the object for later use

You've done steps 1-3 correctly in your code above, and you can execute step 4 the same way. One thing I would recommend, however, is not to overwrite your variables, as this can be confusing when reading the code later.

```
F2 = pd.read_csv("F2.csv", sep =',')
y_test1 = F2['y']
X_test1 = F2.copy()
del X_test1['y']

#add this line, same as you did before
X_test1 =  sc.transform(X_test1)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test1)
```